# How to implement horizontal scrollbar to drop-down in chosen Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-chosen

I need to add a horizontal scroll bar for drop-downs having larger option lengths. We are using Chosen jQuery for these drop-downs.

Below the current code for this:

```
$(".filterDropdown").chosen({allow_single_deselect: true,search_contains: true});
```

In the resultant code, I see that `chzn-results` css is applied which has `overflow-x: hidden;` property. I don't want to directly change this as it may impact UI elsewhere.

Is there a way to provide `overflow-x: auto;` style for these drop-downs?

Comment: You can override the CSS style as you would any other CSS rule; make it more specific, eg. `#container .chzn-results { overflow-x: auto; }`

Comment: `.chzn-results { overflow-x: auto !important; }`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : So for this, I guess it will be better if I wrap these dropdowns in another div... right?

Comment: It doesn't have to be wrapped in a div, but I'm sure there it's already wrapped in *something* which you can use to make the selector more specific.

Comment: @RiteshKhandekar you shouldn't use `!important` unless there is literally no alternative as it makes overriding even more difficult. Use selector specificity instead.